# How do i get the oldest date from a selection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a selection of dates:

```
2015-09-25T11:08:00
2015-09-25T11:42:00
2015-09-25T17:02:00
2015-09-25T17:02:00
2015-09-28T13:09:00
```

How would i get the most recent date from this selection. I was trying to use

```
@messagedaterows.max {|obj| @message_thread_ID }
```

Comment: how are they stored?   Is this selection in a form? are they an array of datetime objects stored in @messagedaterows ?

Comment: @Doon I currently have them being called via 
'messagedate                = options['Messages'].each do |entry|
      messagedaterows = entry["Date"]
    end'

Answer (score 0):

```
2.0.0p353 :005 > test
 => [2015-09-28 17:36:51 +0200, 2015-09-27 17:36:51 +0200] 
2.0.0p353 :006 > test.sort
 => [2015-09-27 17:36:51 +0200, 2015-09-28 17:36:51 +0200] 
2.0.0p353 :007 > test.sort.first
 => 2015-09-27 17:36:51 +0200 
2.0.0p353 :008 > test.sort.last
 => 2015-09-28 17:36:51 +0200
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need complex logic for this.

Simply:

```
dates.max # => 2015-09-28 13:09:00
```

Even if they are strings this should work:

```
dates.max # => "2015-09-28T13:09:00"
```

Answer (score 0):

The *oldest date* is also the *minimal date*. Therefore I would write something like this:

```
dates = options['Messages'].map { |entry| entry["Date"] }
dates.min
#=> 2015-09-25T11:08:00
```

Comment: he asks `most recent date`

Comment: That works however as it is an iteration it is returning two dates as there are two records. How do i return one single record which is the oldest/newest?

Comment: @user3385136 : I do not understand your question. `dates.min` returns just one element (not multiple elements). Perhaps you want to assign it to a variable, like `@min_date = dates.min`?